# Count of each status in gridview yii2

Tags: yii2

In gridview in the first colums is a list of countries. Next columns is status columns. In sql i get it like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_customFields
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method = 'us' AND
order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' AND
`order`.order_status = 'sent'
```

How could I get count of orders for each status and each country? Like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'new' then 1 else 0 end) newtcount,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'arrived' then 1 else 0 end) arrivedcount,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end) sentcount
FROM order_customFields
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
   `order`.order_status
```